# How to rotate HTML content so that the order changes every 30 seconds with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically i have created a single one column which holds 3 articles, i have given all the articles id's i.e news1,news2,news3 and added content to each accordingly [text and img,plus header]

What i am attempting to do is move the content of

article 1 to the location of article 2
article 2 to the location of article 3
article 3 to the location of article 1

with the articles changing location, every 30 seconds,[the above loop] i have tried appendTo,yesterday thought about fadeout, fadein, using a slide i persume would be; going a little over board in terms of code i think, then again on seconds thought..hmmm

i would rather change the content as one lot than, in parts, i.e headers, paragraphs, images etc.

this is how i started, the idea is if i can get it to work in one pair the rest would, straight forward, to do, be it copy and paste, with a edit of selectors.

```
setInterval(function(){
var x = getElementById("#news1");
(this).appendTo("#news3");
}, 30000);
```

Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction, either by illustrating an example or an event 'action' to check out that might do the trick

Comment: Maybe show us your HTML markup so we can give you better guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this.  Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JayAChTee/ybxby29h/20/) using jQuery that leaves you lots of room for improving.  While you can certainly use a variable to hold the DIV's content I just used a hidden DIV as a temporary content holder.  You could also optimize the `rotateNews()` function by holding the four DIV pointers in variables e.g. `var $news1 = $("#new1");` placed first in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of the DOM manipulation, are those methods form Node reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node that handles nodes like `insertBefore`, `removeChild`, `appendChild` an so on

For example the folowing uses standard dom manip. to shift the last element to first position in the tree stack. Read the comments for explanations:

```
  // cache the container element
  var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
  // This is a live reference to the child node finds the last child.
  // The querySelector was use here in order to get a controll over 
  // what elements category should be manipulated
  var lastEl = containerEl.querySelector('.article:last-child');
  // move the element in front - remove from parent
  containerEl.removeChild(lastEl);
  // attach it back in the front.
  containerEl.insertBefore(lastEl, containerEl.firstChild);
```

Now the second part of your problem is the timed event. you can use either `requestAnimationFrame` or a timer or a interval.

I personalty prefer the timer solution since is retro-compatible and it has no chance of executing the scheduled code simultaneous and you can stop the chaning internally without having a reference to the timerId. Maybe `requestAnimationFrame` is a better option, but that is up to you.

To chain schedule the executions a simple recursion does the trick:

```
var timerIdx;
var chainInterval = 6000; // in millis

var callback = function (){
  // the execution code here;
  timerIdx = setTimeout(callback, chainInterval);
};
```

to start it you just call :

```
callback();
```

to stop it you just call :

```
clearTimeout(timerIdx);
```

Now lets put everything together, the style is just for showcasing:

```js
// cache the container element
var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
var timerIdx;
var chainInterval = 1000; // in millis

var chainRotate = function (){
  rotateChildElements(containerEl, '.article')
  timerIdx = setTimeout(chainRotate, chainInterval);
};


var rotateChildElements = function(containerEl, childClassName){
  // This is a live reference to the child node
  var lastEl = containerEl.querySelector(childClassName+':last-child');
  // move the element in front
  containerEl.removeChild(lastEl);
  containerEl.insertBefore(lastEl, containerEl.firstChild);
 };

// Start
chainRotate();



var rotateBtn = document.getElementById('rotateBtn');
rotateBtn.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
   if (timerIdx !== null){
    ev.target.innerHTML = "Start Rotate";
    clearTimeout(timerIdx);
    timerIdx = null;
   } else {
    ev.target.innerHTML = "Stop Rotate";
    chainRotate(); 
   }
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing : border-box;
}

#container {
 position: relative;
 
 margin-left : auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding : 8px;
 border : 1px dashed magenta;
 max-width : 500px;
}

#container:after {
  content : "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.article:first-child {
 margin-left : -4px;
}

.article:last-child {
 margin-right : -4px;
}

.article {
  float: left;
  width : 33.333%;
  margin-right : 4px;
  border : 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="article">
    A content
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    B content
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    C cotntent
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
<button id="rotateBtn">Stop rotate</button>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: FYI, `we don't need no education`. not yours anyway.

Comment: nothing wrong I guess, just your last statement about educating made me think about pink floyd

Answer (score -1):

Pure javascript solution: store the contents of you divs inside variables, then reassign the content of each div to other divs according to your needs.

```
setInterval(function(){
    var contents_n1 = document.getElementById("news1").innerHTML;
    var contents_n2 = document.getElementById("news2").innerHTML;
    var contents_n3 = document.getElementById("news3").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("news1").innerHTML = contents_n3;
    document.getElementById("news2").innerHTML = contents_n1;
    document.getElementById("news3").innerHTML = contents_n2;
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Document.getElementById should not contain the `#` char and quality wise is a bad approach from my standpoint.